# Youtube playback stopped after few minutes

Tags: webkit

I am integrating the youtube(Webkit) feature in my STB, but the video playback stops after few minutes.

In this problematic case the browser does not call any append source buffer.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share the code you used to integrate YouTube? Can you clarify what you mean by STB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STB

Comment: STB means Set Top Box. i am using webkit version 2.